# Create Primary Keys for Realm

Tags: javascript, realm

Iam using Realm as Database backend for my react-native app.
Since Realm doesn't offer an auto creation for primary keys I would just increment the last known ID by 1.

How can I get the last known ID?

Comment: Have you committed to using an ID property that auto increments? I would suggest using a UUID string property for the ID instead. That is what I use and the realm team suggests usually. Every situation is different, but usually this path is better.

Comment: Ok i could do this - to be honest, I didn't think about this possibility...

Comment: To answer your original question, you would use [realm query](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#queries) API to get all objects of a certain model, get the last item from the array result, then get the ID property from the model. I would recommend using UUID if you are able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function logic

```
class MySchema extends Realm.Object {}
MySchema.schema = {
 name: "MySchema", 
 primaryKey: 'id',
 properties: {
  id: "int",
  myProperty: "string", 
 }
const myRealm = new Realm({
    schema: MySchema,
})
getPrimaryKeyId(model) {
if (myRealm .objects(model).max("id")) {
  return myRealm.objects(model).max("id") + 1;
}
return 1;
}
insertQuery(){
 myRealm..write(() => {
 realm.create("MySchema",{id:getPrimaryKeyId('MySchema'), myProperty:'propertyValue'});
 })
}
```

}`

Comment: Hi @gokulp, could you add more detail to your answer?